# call other activity by calling a method

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to call  activity B from Activity A. I want to write method in activity A in which i want to write code for calling activity B. also for this method i want to use two array of strings as  method arguments, so that i can call this method from another activity by passing two array of strings. please help to acheive this . thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [tutorial to switch between activities](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/)